# Trying to write javascript to hide toggle side menu class until page is loaded. It currently shows for a split second until page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggleclass

**EDIT- Got it figured out, answer is below, thanks everyone!**

I'm back with another head scratcher that I've been working on all morning and can't seem to solve on my own and was hoping someone would help out this rookie.

I currently have a problem with my phpbb forum when in responsive mode on my phone (can't duplicate it on desktop using mobile view, but it is happening on my phone and I assume most other phones since mine isn't much different than any other android).

So my problem is that my toggle side menu is loading before I would like it to.  The easiest way to explain is with a picture I made (couldn't screenshot it because it doesn't stay long enough).

[image: mock up of my problem]

As you can see, for about a second (or fraction of a second, just long enough to bug me), the header expands and the menu items are visible.  It doesn't show exactly as it would if the toggle was activated, for some reason, only the text and border items are visible.  The background color does stay hidden.  The background of the header does expand with the text, which is shouldn't do with when the toggle is activated, so I'm not exactly sure what I need to do, hoping I can get some help.

I didn't just come here hoping someone could do this for me, I've tried many many options.

I saw a similar question where it was advised to use #selector within the .css, but I had no luck with that.

I've tried this script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Short-form of `document.ready`
$(function(){
    $(".gf-menu-device-container").hide();
    $(".gf-menu-toggle").on("click", function(){
        $(".gf-menu-device-container").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

The code does nothing for me.  I've also tried substituting .gf-menu-device-wrapper-sidemenu but nothing with that either.

Here's the html code for that menu, The javascript file is minified and nearly impossible for me to get anything out of, but if anyone would like to look at it, it's here:
https://raiderforums.com/styles/corvus/template/rt_js/mootools-core.js

```
<div style="display: block;" class="gf-menu-toggle">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</div>

<div class="gf-menu-device-wrapper-sidemenu">
    <div class="gf-menu-device-container">
        <div class="gf-menu-device-container-wrapper">
            <ul class="gf-menu rt-desktop-menu l1  ">
                 <li class="items would follow">
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing it with `style="display: none"` property?

Comment: when I add: <div class="gf-menu-device-container style="display: none"></div> the menu items are hidden when I click, but they still show on load??

Comment: I hope that's supposed to be `<div class="gf-menu-device-container" style="display: none"></div>`.

Comment: yes, I did it as your typed it, it was a typo in my response (I did make the mistake initially though).

Comment: OK, using the ul class "gf-menu rt-desktop-menu l1" with display:none, I'm able to load on the phone without the menu items showing, but I can't get my script to display it on load.  I've tried this one now with no luck: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
        jQuery('.gf-menu rt-desktop-menu l1').fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it, thanks for the help guys. Changed the inline css to display:none, then this script got it working:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function(){ jQuery('.gf-menu').fadeIn(1000); }); 
</script>
```

See anything wrong with what I did? It works, but perhaps I could have done it different?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
display: none;
```

as it has been mentioned.
Though if you need to use calculations like height, etc before showing it, like `contentHeight` etc., this is not appropriate.

In this case you may use

```
opacity: 0.015;
```

or similar in CSS or even inline, and reset the opacity to 1 *after* hiding it via JavaScript.
This way it may not be that disturbing.

(Yes I know, inline CSS is *ugly* but blinking boxes are more that.)

Comment: I've got that part, the display none inline in my menu.html with "gf-menu rt-desktop-menu l1"  It hides it the way I would want, but I can't get any of my javascripts to function in a way that will display it on load.

Comment: I got it, gonna update and upvote everyone who answered, thanks for the help.